# Attachment removed from email by Lightning email template: prevent / fix possible?

Tags: lightning, email-template

This is something that worked perfectly in Classic, but not in Lightning. Let's say you want to send a quote PDF to a customer. You select the email option from the dropdown menu to the right of the PDF. An email popup window appears in the lower righthand corner of the screen with the PDF attached. Now select an email template (it doesn't matter if you select a Classic or a Lightning template), confirm the application and the attachment is removed from the email. Send the mail to the customer and expect a reply asking for the attachment.

Salesforce knows this, it is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CHXQA2). Which they are **not** going to fix:

> This behaviour has been confirmed as working as Expected thus the 'No
> Fix' status.

Excuse me, "working as Expected"? I don't think so. Anyway, a workaround is for the user to select the attachment (again!) after selecting the template. This is annoying, error prone and it worked perfectly in Classic!

I have been thinking about how I could solve this. If a quote only has one PDF, then I think it is possible to solve this using a trigger. But what if a quote has more than one PDF, which one was originally attached to the email?

Has anyone attempted to solve this and succeeded?

Comment: No solution, but there is an Idea for it that you can vote on: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhYoUAJ/keep-quote-pdf-as-attached-in-email-after-adding-an-lightning-email-template Also, your link to the Known Issue is broken now. Salesforce moved a lot of support pages, and unfortunately didn't redirect all the URLs.